# Use Provided Display Name from From Address in Outlook / Exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, smtp, exchange-2010

A while back I wrote a service which sends out messages when issues occur.  In each non-production environment I've used the same test account to send these messages, but have changed the FROM display name, appending it with the name of the environment.  This worked well as a means to identify the source of a mail until we upgraded to Exchange Server 2010.  At this point, the system started overwriting the given display name with the AD/exchange name for the service account/from address.

The display name provided still displays in the header text (i.e. open the mail, go to file, info, properties, then look through the internet headers for FROM: and the environment is clearly stated.

Is there any way to tell outlook to use this (provided) display name instead of exchange's name when listing mails from this account?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your reponse works very specifically for you. I have launched a similar question on Microsoft's TechNet forums. The change has to come from the Exchange 2010 side in my opinion as it affects Outlook, iPhone and Android clients. They are definitely replacing the display name in the From line in the header with AD/Exchange name. I'm somewhat annoyed. Here is the link to the TechNet submission, hopefully someone will shed light on it there. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/3da4928e-eaa3-420e-b5fe-404f19d822ac

Comment: @David Can you summarize the contents of the linked thread when you get a response at the TechNet forums?

Comment: Thanks for the link @David.  FYI: the same question's also up on Experts' Exchange - though so far there's no answer on there: www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_26236683.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my issue, provided here for anyone with the same issue in future. . .

Create a new rule in outlook, as below:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
with (PRODUCTION) in the message header
assign it to the PRODUCTION category
```

The above rule interrogates the email's message header (viewable by opening the message then selecting File, Info, Properties) for a specific string.  In my case, emails from the Production system had "(Production)" in the header, whilst those from non-production had "(SIT / UAT / Regression)".  Based on this condition the rule then applies one of Outlook's categories (I renamed PURPLE to PRODUCTION so that Outlook could remember which colour related to which environment on my behalf).